# expr = expr.replace( rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" ); error during upgrading js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to upgrade jQuery-1.10.2.js on my existing programs which had version 1.7.2.
I already set  Migrate Plugin  1.2.1 too as posted on jQuery [blog](http://jquery.com/download/)

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JS_PATH;?>jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JS_PATH;?>jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"</script>
```

But clicking the submit button gives the following error:

> TypeError: expr.replace is not a function
>   expr = expr.replace( rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" );  on  jquery-1.10.2.js (line 1798)

In case of migrate plugin, is it required to code inside our programs or does the code convert itself from the old version to the new one?

Any solution for this problem?